# QR code data scanned type objective c

Tags: objective-c, qr-code

I'm trying to integrate a functionality in an app that scans a QR code with multiple type of data.
My question is, is there a way to know the type of data scanned from the QR code?

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886764/objective-c-is-it-possible-to-detect-qr-code-data-type?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C : is it possible to detect QR code data type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886764/objective-c-is-it-possible-to-detect-qr-code-data-type)